# how to make XCode 4.5 Organizer Documentation help similar to earlier versions

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.5

This is one of my biggest turn offs from the newer versions of XCode(ie 4.5+) is the following: in earlier versions.. when you `option click` a system defined function.. you get a bubble that offers you a link that takes you directly to the function definition in organizer:

[image]

[image]

**but on XCode 4.5 and later.. that changed:** the exact link of the function is no longer provided.. instead you can only click on the reference of the *entire class!*

any idea how that can be changed? Another problem I have is the fact that I just couldn't figure out how to do offline documentation viewing on xcode 4.5 (it worked fine in earlier versions.. and yes i did download all the documentation locally and followed all the SOF links.. but no luck!)..

[image]
[image]

Comment: When I click on the UITableViewCell Class Reference link at the bottom, it still takes me to the function definition.

Comment: can you do offline viewing? maybe if i got that right.. then organizer will become more accurate?

Comment: I click on "Organizer" and then go to the documentation tab.  I assume it is offline because it shows my custom docs as well, which are nowhere on the internet.

Comment: Documentation is installed as .docset files.  It's entirely local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you download all the documentation locally via XCode->Preferences. Once it's local there should be no problem accessing specific functions through the popup - it says "Class Reference" but it automatically opens the relevant documentation within the class reference.

Comment: you're actually right.. i tried downloading the docs and now both problems are solved: offline viewing and accurate function linking.. thanks!